# How to get link using Xpath in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, xpath, puppeteer

I am trying to get the link connected to this href

```
<a href="http://e epurl.com/g-em6v" title="Late Night 1 Love" target="_blank">Late Night 1 Love</a>
```

(I had to add space between url)
I was able to get the text content via the following method

```
const [el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="archive-list"]/div/li[1]');
    const txt = await el.getProperty("textContent");
    const rawTxt = await txt.jsonValue();
```

```
  const [link] = await page.$x('//*[@id="archive-list"]/div/li[1]/a');
     const L = await string('//*[@id="archive-list"]/div/li[1]/a/@href'); 
    console.log(L);
```

I am having trouble extracting the link itself, I was hoping this would work but does not appear to be so simple.

I am using Puppeteer to get to the page in order to access the elements.

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(L);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the easiest way to use [`page.evaluate`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.1.0&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to get the properties of an element. It looks like this: `page.evaluate(pageFunction[, ...args])`the pageFunction is evaluated in the page context where [ElementHandle](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.1.0&show=api-class-elementhandle) instances can be passed as arguments. As the XPath handle returns an array (with a length of `1`) you can use the 1st element on the `[0]` index.

For example:

```js
const link = await page.evaluate(el => el.href, (await page.$x('//*[@id="archive-list"]/div/li[1]/a'))[0])
console.log(link)
```

Comment: Thank you! sorry for late reply, I ended up using cheerio and was able to access the elements way easier haha. I just tried your code and it did in fact work! I will test it against the one I have to see which is more efficient!